# How to cancel running azure yaml pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-releases

I have a yaml pipeline which has three stages. All stages having jobs and I have around 10-12 tasks in each job.

When run pipeline and if I cancel it, it keeps running in background until all task executed. It does not go to next stage after I cancel.
How can we stop pipeline as soon as i hit cancel?
We have property called **cancelTimeoutInMinutes** which i set to 1. It also does not work.

I dont want to wait after cancel till all tasks gets completed.
Need help.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of conditions do you have on the tasks in the stage? For example, if your tasks have `condition: always()`, they will always run even if the pipeline itself is cancelled. There are other combination of conditions that can result in similar effects, so check each task's condition.

Comment: No. I don't have any conditions on any task.